# Is there a better way of refactoring this piece of code?

Tags: c#

This is just the sample code. I was wondering if there is a better way of  replacing if block

```
public enum FileType
{
    Unknown = 0,
    Text = 1,
    Word = 2,
    Excel = 3,
    Csv = 4
}

private static string GetFormatedFile(string fileName)
{
    var file = FileType.Unknown;

    if (fileName.Contains(".txt"))
    {
         file = FileType.Text;
    }
    else if(fileName.Contains(".doc"))
    {
         file = FileType.Word;
    }
    else if(fileName.Contains(".xlsx"))
    {
          file = FileType.Excel;
    }
    else if (fileName.Contains(".csv"))
    {
           file = FileType.Csv;
    }

    switch (file)
    {
         case FileType.Text: return fileName.Split(".")[3];
         case FileType.Word: return fileName.Split("_")[4];
         case FileType.Excel: return fileName.Split(".")[3];
         case FileType.Csv: return fileName.Split("_")[4];
         default: throw new NotSupportedException($"File Type not ready => {file}");
    }
}
```

Comment: Another switch statement on the string fileName

Comment: What are you trying to retrieve by doing a `fileName.Split(".")` etc? What does you filename look like?

Comment: My file name looks like app_update_text_Illi_WORD10I.1251.1.20180723-04.txt.gz. I am trying to extract the portion of my filename

Comment: You could have more/better answers by asking on codereview.stackexchange.com, but I haven't used this site so I am not sure.

Comment: You should edit the question and post possible patterns of the file name and clearly define your constraints. For example, is it always a `.gz` file, and the part preceding it always one of your extensions? Also looks like your file name is different depending on whether it's a Word, Excel file etc. You should show all that info, otherwise it's impossible to show you a correct answer.

Comment: For example, when your file type is `.doc` why do you split on `_`. Because the index `4` or your resulting array will be `WORD10I.1251.1.20180723-04.doc.gz` if your file extension is `.doc`. Is that what you need?

Comment: This type of question (code that works, seeking review) are better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
interface IFileNameProvider
{
    string GetFileName(string name);
    bool CanHandle(string name);
} 

class WordCsvFileNameProvider : IFileNameProvider
{
    public string GetFileName(string name){
        return name.Split("_")[4];
    }

    public bool CanHandle(string name){
        return name.Contains(".doc") || name.Contains(".csv");
    }
} 

class TextExcelFileNameProvider : IFileNameProvider
{
    public string GetFileName(string name){
        return name.Split(".")[3];
    }

    public bool CanHandle(string name){
        return name.Contains(".txt") || name.Contains(".xlsx");
    }
}
```

You inject the providers and then use them as follows:

```
private static string GetFormatedFile(string fileName)
{
    var provider = fileNameProviders.FirstOrDefault(fnp => fnp.CanHandle(fileName));

    if(provider == null)
        throw new NotSupportedException($"File Type not ready => {file}");

    return provider.GetFileName(fileName);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can map your extensions in a dictionary and then do a lookup like so:

```cs
var map = 
    new Dictionary<String, FileType>()
    {
        {".txt", FileType.Text},
        {".doc", FileType.Word},
        {".xlsx", FileType.Excel},
        {".csv", FileType.Csv},
    };

var file = FileType.Unknown;
if (map.TryGetValue(Path.GetExtension(fileName), out var type))
{
    file = type;
}
```

Comment: based on his comments, it's not the extension, as OP's filenames look like this `app_update_text_Illi_WORD10I.1251.1.20180723-04.txt.gz`

Comment: Magnetron: this .gz comment was made after I posted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can just get rid of the `enum` and `switch` altogether.

```
private static string GetFormatedFile(string fileName)
{
    var ext = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
    switch (ext)
    {
        case ".txt":
            return fileName.Split(new char[] { '.' })[3]; break;
        case ".doc":
            return fileName.Split(new char[] { '_' })[3]; break;
        default:
            throw new NotSupportedException("$"File Type not ready => {ext}"");
    }
}
```

Comment: based on his comments, it's not the extension, as OP's filenames look like this `app_update_text_Illi_WORD10I.1251.1.20180723-04.txt.gz`

Comment: @Magnetron I see, yes the comments weren't there initially. I'll edit the answer.